# MySql - running a script with a trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

Suppose I have a script with the code for a trigger, how do I actually start up the script so that the trigger is active? How do I stop it?

Comment: More information please. Code example perhaps?

Comment: It is just a simple trigger saved in a .sql file. I do not know how to run(execute) this file.

Comment: @Trup Does the below answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a script that has code for creating a MySQL trigger, you would simply execute the script in order to create the trigger assuming the script contains MySQL statements along the lines of:

```
CREATE
    [DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
    TRIGGER trigger_name trigger_time trigger_event
    ON tbl_name FOR EACH ROW trigger_body
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html

To get rid of a trigger that you have created, you use the `DROP` statement in MySQL accompanied by the name of the trigger, or create another script to execute the SQL statement:

```
DROP TRIGGER [IF EXISTS] [schema_name.]trigger_name
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/drop-trigger.html

To execute a SQL file you would simply type `@[file_name].sql` at the SQL prompt in the command line:

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/script.php